# How to install Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 with IE11 installed?

Tags: windows-7, installation, internet-explorer-9

I'm developing a website and it's experiencing issues on IE9 (so I've been told). To debug the site, I need to uninstall IE11 and install IE9 (Windows does not allow one to have two versions installed simultaneously).

I already downloaded IE9 and then removed IE11 by going to Programs and Software in Windows 7, followed by choosing "Uninstall Windows Features", disabling "Internet Explorer 11", and rebooting my system.

However, even after uninstalling IE11, the IE9 installer will complain that "Internet Explorer 9 is already installed on this system.", which is definitely not true.

Is there any way for me to install Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 with IE11 installed?

Comment: IE9 and IE11 cannot exist on the same installation of Windows. If you have a need for an instance of IE9 there are **FREE** virtual machine images that Microsoft offers for that purpose.  If you want to uninstall IE11 you just [uninstall](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/wiki/ie11-windows_7/how-to-uninstall-internet-explorer-10-or-internet/4e280525-1856-4fa1-bb16-efda4ea8b5f1%20) it and that will revert you back to the previously installed version of IE.

Comment: https://www.modern.ie/en-us

Comment: After you removed IE11, what version of IE were you left with?

Comment: Why not use them at the same time using: [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575)

Comment: @LPChip that would require me to install a VM and purchase a new windows license, right?

Comment: @Tom You need a VM yes, but not a license.

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to downgrade Internet Explorer 11 the wrong way.

## Steps:

1. You will need to undo the changes you have made thus far by refreshing the Internet Explorer installation. Go to `Control Panel`, then `Uninstall Windows Features`, and enable `Internet Explorer 11`. Reboot the system.
2. Uninstall Internet Explorer. Go to `Control Panel`, then `Programs and Features`, on the left find `View Installed Updates`, under `Microsoft Windows` look for `Internet Explorer 11`, and then right click and remove the update. Reboot the machine, and you will have Internet Explorer reverted to the previous Internet Explorer you had installed. Windows 7 originally shipped with IE8 (REF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8 and some later releases had IE9 (REF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9 ).